# How to bind repeater of Web User Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, webusercontrol

I am really confused .Wasted 1 full day for it but still not able to fix .I made a (Repeater.ascx)web user control(having Repeater inside) and then drag it on aspx page(Info.aspx) like this.

```
   <uc1:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater" />
```

This is user control code.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Repeater.ascx.cs" Inherits="DBG.Website.Billing.Repeater" %>
 <asp:Repeater ID="repeaterInvoicesPaid"    OnItemCommand="ClientNameClicked" runat="server">
               <HeaderTemplate>
            <table id="PaidInvoicesTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; font-size: 11px; border-right-width: 0; border-bottom-width: 0;"
            class="dxgvControl grid dxgvTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 150px;" class="dxgvHeader">Invoice #
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 150px;" class="dxgvHeader">Client Name
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 150px;" class="dxgvHeader">Invoice Date
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 150px;" class="dxgvHeader">Due Date
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 150px;" class="dxgvHeader">Total
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 150px;" class="dxgvHeader">Payment Method
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 150px;" class="dxgvHeader">Status

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
              <tbody>
            </HeaderTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr class="dxgvDataRow">
                    <td class="dxgv">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblInvoiceID" Text='<%#Eval("InvoiceID")%>' runat="server" /> 
                    </td>
                    <td class="dxgv">
                   <asp:LinkButton ID="btnClientName"  CommandName="NameClicked"  Text='<%#Eval("ClientName")%>' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("InvoiceReapterCustomerID") %>' runat="server"/>

                    </td>

                    <td class="dxgv">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblAddedDate" Text='<%#Eval("AddedDateAndTime")%>' runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="dxgv">
                   <asp:Label ID="lblCloseDate" Text='<%#Eval("CloseDateOnly") %>' runat="server" />

                    </td>
                    <td class="dxgv">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRecurringCharge" Text='<%#Eval("RecurringCharge") %>' runat="server" />

                    </td>
                    <td class="dxgv">
                      <asp:Label ID="lblPaymentMethodID"  Text='<%#Eval("PaymentMethodIDInvoices")%>' runat="server" />

                    </td>
          <td class="dxgv">

           <asp:Label ID="lblStatus"   ForeColor="Green"  Text=' <%#Eval("StatusType") %>' runat="server" />

          </td>
                        <td class="dxgv">

           <asp:Label ID="lblCustomerid"   Visible="false"  Text=' <%#Eval("InvoiceReapterCustomerID") %>' runat="server" />

          </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>

   <FooterTemplate>

            </tbody> 


       </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Now my problem is that i want to bind the repeater of web user control inside info.cs file but i do not how to get user control and repeater id on info.cs and bind it .

Note:i need to bind repeater with datasource(List) return from a info.cs's method.

Please Help .
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a public method in your control and call it from the page.

**In ASCX**

```
public void BindRepeater()
{
    //.....
    repeaterInvoicesPaid.DataSource = datatableOrDataSet;
    repeaterInvoicesPaid.DataBind();
}
```

**In ASPX**

```
uc1.BindRepeater();
```

Comment: ucl is not recognized it says "uc1 does not exist in current context".

Comment: You have to give the id of user control contain repeater, you can see in your html. uc1 is just an example give the id you have for user control.

Comment: right.but i think the user control's control are by default protected or private so it is giving me access protection issue.
how can i make them public?

Comment: You will need to modify its access specifier, a better option could be  a public method of user control which will be called from page to bind repeater.

Comment: Thanks it is solved now...:)
a last question i need to clear.Actually i need to use same user control on two aspx pages(say info.aspx and data.aspx).Can i access Page_Load event of info.cs inside Page_Load event of data.cs.?I am asking because info.cs binding the repeater at page load ,so i need to do same for data.cs.

Comment: I think your problem is solved by the other answer, do you still need help?

Answer (score 0):

Typically for vanilla ASP.NET if you specify an ID and the runat="server" attribute you can access the control from the code of the aspx page. It's important to access post initialize where the controls get created - your best choice would be in the OnLoad event.

What you have to remember is when you set the datasource/itemssource, you have to call the .Bind() or .DataBind() method aftewards to do the actual binding.